# Z tables normal distribution $P(10 - c < X < 10 + c) = 0.95$. Find c. For N(10, 2)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

$P(10 - c < X < 10 + c) = 0.95$. Find c

attempt:

$P(10 - c < X < 10 + c) = \phi(\frac{10 + c - 10}{\sqrt{2}}) - \phi(\frac{10-c-10}{\sqrt{2}}) = \phi(\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}) - (1 - \phi(\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}})) = 2\phi(\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}) - 1$

$0.975 = \phi(\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}})$

not sure how to simplify to $\phi$. I know $\phi(0.975) \approx 0.834$ according to Z table. How do I compute the inverse?

$\phi^{-1}(0.975) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$

using the Z table.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/68–95–99.7_rule

Comment: Assuming that the _variance_ of your normal dist'n is 2, you have $P(-c/\sqrt{2} < Z < c/\sqrt{2}) = .95.$ So according to printed normal tables $c/\sqrt{2} = 1.96,$ where $Z$ is standard normal. You can solve this for $c.$ // Also a point of notation: $\phi$ or $\varphi$ is used for the standard normal PDF, while $\Phi$ is used for the standard normal CDF, as here. [To get $\Phi,$ type `$\Phi$`.]