# Find $X$ in $P(-x < 10 - x < x) = 0.95$ (normal distribution)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I tried:

$$P(-x < 10 - x < x) = 0.95 \Leftrightarrow \\
P(10-x <x) -P(10-x > -x) = 0.95 \Leftrightarrow \\
P(10 < 0) -P(10>0) = 0.95$$

This makes no sense? Why?

$\mu=10$ and the standard deviation is $2$.

I found this: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071463/z-tables-normal-distribution-p10-c-x-10-c-0-95-find-c-for-n10)

I can see that the OP did basically what I did but did the standardization directly.Why does it work if done that way and doesn't work the way I did it?

For comparison, here's a problem that uses a standard normal curve:

$$P(-z < Z < z) = 0.95 \Leftrightarrow \\
P(Z<z)-P(Z<-z) = 0.95 \Leftrightarrow \\
P(Z<z) -(1-P(Z<z))=0.95\Leftrightarrow \\
2P(Z<z)-1=0.95 \Leftrightarrow P(Z<z)=0.975$$

Then I look it up in the Z table, etc.. my question is, why is it that what I tried to do works here but not in the first problem?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.$P(10-X>-X)=P(10>0)=1$ so the equation becomes $P(10-X<X)=1.95$, which is impossible. Do you mean the original problem is $P(-C<X-10<C)=0.95$?

Comment: @zugzug Oops, turns out I completely ignored the case of the letters... sorry it's almost 3am. That x in the middle is supposed to be uppercase.

Comment: Anyways, assuming it's $P(-x<10-X<x)=0.95$, the idea is the left hand side is equivalent to $P(|10-X|<x)=P(|X-10|<x)=P(-x<X-10<x)$. When you divide all terms in the inequality by $\sigma$, you can solve the problem in a similar way to the one you linked to.

Comment: @zugzug Yeah, got it

Comment: This is why paying attention to case sensitivity is important.